# Converting a.py file with supporting files to .exe

Tags: python

My folder contains a .py file and this python file uses other .exe files for its functioning. And I want to convert that python file and the .exe file into one executable file.

When I tried to do so using pyinstaller or auto-py-to-exe, its not successful. the executable throws an error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question is way too vague. What error is it giving?

Comment: this is kind of a work around more than a solution but you can to convert the `.py` file into an executable, and then place the 2 executables into a self extracting exe wrapper

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `C:\Users\aragh>auto-py-to-exe

D:\Softwares\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py:175: UserWarning: The numpy.array_api submodule is still experimental. See NEP 47.
  __import__(package)`


This is the error i got after using auto-py-to-exe

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by regular methods as far as I can tell. You can interpret your .py files into an .exe file and then concat one exe to another using a dissassembler. Its not something you want to do unless you know what you are doing.

What you can do, is compile your .py file into an exe using Pyinstaller for instance, and compile a second script that is using both your normal exe and your pyinstaller exe's for instance with command line arguments, or subprocesses.

Good luck!

Comment: That feels like a nice idea!. Will try and get back to you! thanks!
but the problem i think i will face is the code that i am using requires streamlit.

Comment: If this was the answer please approve / disapprove :)

Comment: I cant, it wasnt helpful